# How to prevent your web page to display in IE?

Tags: html

I am working on my first project and it looks OK in Chrome and Opera. But for some reason the "Signature Chef dish" section, looks off on Firefox. I suspect it has something to do with the grid I implemented there?

How can I fix this?

Also I want to disable view in the IE and it looks like a complete mess. Why?

URL: http://www.chefmarwanslim.com

The code:

https://github.com/Igor2122/marwan-3-0.git

Answer (score 0):

In order to 'block' IE, just check what browser is being used and than change the page accordingly, in the case of IE you just display "Please upgrade to a decent browser". You could also add a link to firefox or chrome in that message if you want to. In order to detect what browser is used, please look at [How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser).

Feedback for the site
The site looks nice, but the SIGNATURE CHEF DISH section isn't consistent. It would be better if the tweets and 'normal' pictures where displayed the same way or if you'd only use one of the two.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback !!! will try to work on the design of the Signature section.

Comment: If the answer was enough, could you please accept it as a solution?